# Oracle Database connections always miss the DRCP cache

Tags: php, oracle

I have configured Oracle to use DRCP and setup PHP to connect to the pooled connection, but when I pull the connection stats there are always zero hits while the number of requests and number of misses continues to climb.

```
CCLASS_NAME             NUM_REQUESTS NUM_HITS NUM_MISSES NUM_WAITS  WAIT_TIME CLIENT_REQ_TIMEOUTS   
BIGTUNACAN.drcp_pooling_test    9828        0       9828         6     0     0
```

My connection in tnsnames.ora is using SERVER = POOLED and my php.ini has drcp_pooling_test set.

I'm at a loss right now why cached connections would never be used.

TNS entry below

```
TESTPOOL.WORLD =

   (DESCRIPTION =

     (ADDRESS_LIST =

       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = test-db.bigtunacan.com)(PORT = 1521))

     )

     (CONNECT_DATA =

       (SID = TEST)

       (SERVER = POOLED)

     )

)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire tns entry?  Are you connecting to a service?  (And if so, as far as I know DRCP does not work with the default service.)

Comment: @JonHeller I have added the tns entry and just replaced the host.  We are using SID rather than service names.

Comment: (SID=TEST) might be your issue there. You need to connect to a service, not a sid

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald is there some Oracle documentation describing this?  I'm not disagreeing; I just need something concrete to show to the DBA.

Comment: Unsure - I've not used SID in decades (and neither should anyone else be). Services became the recommendation since way way back in 8i. We can't really comment without seeing the entire DRCP setup you've done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem won't be the use of SID (although you should still change that, since you potentially lose a bunch of inherent functionality), but that you are using `oci_connect()`.  Use `oci_pconnect()` instead.  This is a guess, since you missed giving the testcase.

`NUM_HITS` is the "Total number of times client requests found matching pooled servers and sessions in the pool.", but `oci_connect()` has to recreate the session, so it won't give a 'hit'. See table 11 on page 261 of [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html) which says that `oci_connect()` "Gets a pooled server from the DRCP pool and creates a brand new session.".  You will get some benefits from reusing a pooled server but not the full benefit that `oci_pconnect()` can give you.

However, you should step back and really review why you want DRCP.  If you're not already using `oci_pconnect()` then your PHP connection calls will be slow.  Change to use `oci_pconnect()`.  You may then be able to reduce the number of Apache processes needed, which will reduce the number of concurrent connections needed.  Implement other best practices such as using bind variables.  Only if your database host doesn't have enough memory to handle all the open connections concurrently would you then move to use Shared Servers or DRCP.  DRCP is a pool solution, so there is some overhead (and a small amount of extra administration).